# Are there infinite sets whose aleph and beth numbers are both unknown?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

**Is there a set $S$ that is definable in ZFC and known to be infinite, but for which we know neither the aleph nor beth number?**

For example, we do not know the aleph number of $|\mathbb R|$, but we know its beth number, $|\mathbb R| = \beth_1$. Conversely, we trivially know the aleph number of $\aleph_1$, but we do not know its beth number (or whether it has one).

To be clear, by "not knowing the beth number of $S$" I mean we either know $S$ has a beth number but don't know the particular number, or we don't even know whether $S$ has a beth number. Also, by "not knowing" $X$ I mean either we have shown $X$ to be undecidable in ZFC, or we just don't know in the usual sense.

Comment: Seems difficult to resolve trivialities like $S=0$ if CH, else $S=1$.

Comment: The set $S$ of Mersenne primes? It is conjectured that $|S|=\aleph_0=\beth_0$ but it is not known.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Right, I hadn't thought of that. I guess the spirit of the question is about sets that are defined in a "natural" way without reference to "familiar undecidable" sentences. Not sure if that can be made precise.

Comment: @user14111 Good point, but I just changed the question to exclude unknown finite-vs-infinite cases, since I'm more interested in the case where we know the set is infinite.

Comment: Are you looking for something like $2^{\aleph_1}$? I'm pretty sure it can have more than one aleph/beth value, depending on generalized continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @freakish That should be the answer. $|\mathcal P(\omega_1)|$ can be $\beth_1$ or $\beth_2$ or $\aleph_2$ or $\aleph_3$ or $\aleph_4$ . ..

Comment: @freakish Even better, $2^{\aleph_1}$ might not be a beth number at all! E.g. if $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_3$, and $2^{\aleph_2}=\aleph_4$, so $2^{\aleph_1}$ lies strictly between $\beth_1$ and $\beth_2$.